# How to move cursor to first position in last line of RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

For moving cursor to last position I am using following code(which works fine)

```
rtbLog.SelectionStart = rtbLog.Text.Length;
rtbLog.ScrollToCaret();
```

How to move cursor to first position in last line of RichTextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using last index of `Environment.Newline`:

```
rtbLog.SelectionStart = rtbLog.Text.LastIndexOfAny(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()) + 1 ;
rtbLog.ScrollToCaret();
```